# How to proper use JOIN on JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I am trying to use Criteria API for dynamically filtering and SQL conditioning. My filtering is working but can't do the join clause.
This is my filter&join method.

```
public Page<ReceivedFax> findAllWithFilters(PageRequest pageRequest,
                                            Map<String, String> receivedFaxSearchCriteriaMap, String uuid) {

    CriteriaQuery<ReceivedFax> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ReceivedFax.class);

    Root<ReceivedFax> receivedFaxRoot = criteriaQuery.from(ReceivedFax.class);
    
    Join<ReceivedFax, Account> join = receivedFaxRoot.join("account");
    join.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("uuid"), uuid));
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(join);

    Predicate predicate = getPredicate(receivedFaxSearchCriteriaMap, receivedFaxRoot);
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    TypedQuery<ReceivedFax> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    typedQuery.setFirstResult(pageRequest.getPageNumber() * pageRequest.getPageSize());
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());

    long receivedFaxCount = getReceivedFaxCount(predicate);

    return new PageImpl<>(typedQuery.getResultList(), pageRequest, receivedFaxCount);
}
```

I need to use this SQL:

```
select *
from ReceivedFaxes
         join Accounts A on A.ID = ReceivedFaxes.AccountID
where A.UUID = '522f6084-893f-4063-92d1-b9130fc88400'(uuid);
```

I am getting this error:

```
"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax]. 
Expected arguments are: model.account.Account [
  select new model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax(generatedAlias0) 
  from model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax as generatedAlias1 
  inner join generatedAlias1.account as generatedAlias0 
  with generatedAlias0.uuid=:param0 where 1=1]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax].
 Expected arguments are: model.account.Account [
  select new model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax(generatedAlias0) 
  from model.receivedfax.ReceivedFax as generatedAlias1 
  inner join generatedAlias1.account as generatedAlias0 
  with generatedAlias0.uuid=:param0 where 1=1]"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line?  criteriaQuery.multiselect(join); multiselect is the projection

Comment: I'm trying to join Account Entity to ReceivedFax entity, then give WHERE clause for conditioning.

Comment: Then simply remove  criteriaQuery.multiselect(join);

Answer (score 0):

As Simon mentioned, it was my bad. After removing
 `criteriaQuery.multiselect(join)`
Criteria API is working as it should.